# How to generate random numbers in C++ without using time as a seed

Tags: c++, c++11, random

My program is supposed to generate random number with a fixed maximum of 9999. These numbers are used to create objects. Now the problem is when using time as a seed, if I create two objects one after the other both will be created with the same number (as the time hasn't changed in the process).

How can I do that more efficiently so I can generate a distinct random number every time I run the program?

Comment: did you try the documentation? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random specifically, std::random_device can be used to seed a pseudorandom algorithm

Comment: Please post the relevant code. Some hints meanwhile: consider using `std::chrono`. Also, what do you mean by "using time"? Do you `seed` on each `rand` call (if you use `rand` at all)?

Comment: ***if I create two objects one after the other both will be created with the same number*** Don't reseed the random number generator each time you want a random number. Seed one time at the start of your  `main()`

Comment: If you *need* multiple generators, perhaps for multi-threading reasons, use can use a master generator to seed each new generator.

Comment: @drescherjm: From What I understand, the program output one random number only, and need to be relaunched to get other value

Comment: Random numbers may be random, but they are not unique. If you need *unique* numbers you need a sequence, which is a totally different problem.

Comment: The wording of the question is somewhat confusing however I expect that: ***These numbers are used to create objects. Now the problem is when using time as a seed, if I create two objects one after the other both will be created with the same number*** means the program will generate more than 1 random number per execution. I don't think it means that create 1 object do something useful with the object and execute the same program again in a second. With that said if you started several instances of the program at the same time this would make sense that only 1 number was generated per run.

Answer (score 9):

The key is - create a random object (or its state) only once and then reuse it to get the next value. This approach is commonly used in other languages, for example, Java, C#, Python.

For an older C-style example see [rand](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/), this is the bit you are interested in

```
//initialize random seed ONCE
srand (time(NULL));

// call MANY TIMES for next value
rand();
rand();
rand();
```

The same idea with [C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random), for example with [uniform distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)

```
// Setup ONCE
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, 9999);

// Call MANY TIMES to get next random number 
dis(gen);
dis(gen);
dis(gen);
```

Comment: Since the question has the C++11 tag, maybe it would be more appropriate to post a solution that doesn't involve the old `rand` functionality.

Comment: The question title does also specifically ask how to generate random numbers *without using time as a seed*.

Comment: @JasonR if you read the question you realize that "without using time" is a false-issue, an XY problem. The real problem is that same numbers get generated. The OP falsely concluded that the cause must be time used as seed

Answer (score 1):

A simple C++ class to generate random numbers. The header file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#include <random>  
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector> 

namespace Random
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Secure pseudo random number generator.
    /// </summary>
    class RandomGenerator
    {
    public:
        /// <summary>
        /// Random number generator.
        /// </summary>
        RandomGenerator();

        /// <summary>
        /// Random number generator destructor.
        /// </summary>
        ~RandomGenerator();

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the randomly ordered numbers between the lower bound and upper bound inclusive. Each random value only occurs once.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="lowerBound">The smallest random value to generate.</param>
        /// <param name="upperBound">The largest random value to generate.</param>
        /// <returns>The list of randomly ordered values.</returns>
        /// <exception cref="std::invalid_argument">Invalid parameters.</exception>
        std::vector<int> GetRandomList(int lowerBound = 1, int upperBound = 52);

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the random number between the lower bound and upper bound inclusive.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="lowerBound">The smallest random value to generate.</param>
        /// <param name="upperBound">The largest random value to generate.</param>
        /// <returns>A random value.</returns>
        /// <exception cref="std::invalid_argument">Invalid parameters.</exception>
        int Generate(int lowerBound, int upperBound);

    private:
        bool _disposed;
    };
}
```

And the code file.

```
#include "RandomGenerator.h"

using namespace Random;

/// <summary>
/// Random number generator.
/// </summary>
RandomGenerator::RandomGenerator() : _disposed(false)
{
}

/// <summary>
/// Random number generator destructor.
/// </summary>
RandomGenerator::~RandomGenerator()
{
    // If not disposed.
    if (!_disposed)
    {
         // Indicate that dispose has been called.
         _disposed = true;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Get the randomly ordered numbers between the lower bound and upper bound inclusive. Each random value only occurs once.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="lowerBound">The smallest random value to generate.</param>
/// <param name="upperBound">The largest random value to generate.</param>
/// <returns>The list of randomly ordered values.</returns>
/// <exception cref="std::invalid_argument">Invalid parameters.</exception>
std::vector<int> RandomGenerator::GetRandomList(int lowerBound, int upperBound)
{
    // Validate input.
    if (lowerBound > upperBound)
          throw std::invalid_argument("The parameters are invalid, the lower bound can not be larger then the upper bound.");

    std::vector<int> numbers;
    int arraySize = upperBound - lowerBound + 1;

    // Allocate the total number of values.
    numbers.resize(arraySize);

    // For each value in the bounds.
    for (int i = lowerBound; i <= upperBound; i++)
    {
         // Assign the numbers.
         numbers[i - lowerBound] = i;
    }

    // Non-deterministic generator
    // to seed mersenne twister.
    // Random values on each execution.
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 engine(rd());

    // Shuffle the numbers between the lower and upper bounds.
    std::shuffle(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), engine);

    // Return the randomly ordered numbers.
    return numbers;
}

/// <summary>
/// Get the random number between the lower bound and upper bound inclusive.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="lowerBound">The smallest random value to generate.</param>
/// <param name="upperBound">The largest random value to generate.</param>
/// <returns>A random value.</returns>
/// <exception cref="std::invalid_argument">Invalid parameters.</exception>
int RandomGenerator::Generate(int lowerBound, int upperBound)
{
    // Validate input.
    if (lowerBound > upperBound)
         throw std::invalid_argument("The parameters are invalid, the lower bound can not be larger then the upper bound.");

    int randomValue;

    // Non-deterministic generator
    // to seed mersenne twister.
    // Random values on each execution.
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 engine(rd());

    // Use the uniform distribution to generate
    // a value between lower and upper bound inclusive.
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(lowerBound, upperBound);

    // Generate the random value.
    randomValue = dist(engine);

    // Return the random value.
    return randomValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For better understanding I show you how linear congruential generators works.

For this type of generators the math is really simple:

```
xi+1=(A*xi+B) mod N
```

Where A, B and N are constants.

And the code could be:

```
static unsigned int x;  //the seed (time in your case)

unsigned int myRand(){
    x=A*x+B;    //We do not need modulo because it is implicit. For 32b integer the modulo will be 2^32.
    return x;
}
```

So when you setting x=time, when time doesn't change, you just simply resetting the generator.

So the solution for your problem could be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<10;i++){
        std::cout << random()%(9999+1)<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Or try this different approach:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main() {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0,9999);

    for (unsigned int i=0; i<10;i++){
            std::cout << distribution(gen)<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

More about random_device: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/random_device/

Comment: I am not sure which range is more suitable for Othmane Qadiri. He only said that the maximum is 9999.

Comment: Fair enough, then.